# 2 Templates 1 custom post type according url

Tags: custom-post-types, customization, templates

Let's say i have a custom post type names "Projects", is it possible to have two template like :

- Minimal template (with a few info about the projet)
- Complete template (all the info)

And the template is selected according the url :

site.com/minimal-template/project-1
or
site.com/complete-template/project-1

Is it possible ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`query_vars`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/query_vars/) filter to add a new query variable to store the template version (*minimal* / *complete*).

```
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'se385568_query_vars' );
function se385568_query_vars( $vars )
{
    $vars[] = 'tpl';
    return $vars;
}
```

Add a rewrite rule ([codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_rule/)) to recognize the new link format and set the newly created query variable

```
add_action( 'init', 'se385568_rewrite_rules' );
function se385568_rewrite_rules()
{
    $cpt_slug = 'projects';
    add_rewrite_rule(
        "^(minimal|complete)-template/([^/]+)(?:/([0-9]+))?/?$",
        'index.php?'. $cpt_slug .'=$matches[2]&tpl=$matches[1]&page=$matches[3]',
        'top'
    );
}
```

Use the [`template_include`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_include/) filter to change the loaded template based on your query variable.

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'se385568_project_template', 90 );
function se385568_project_template()
{
    $qv = get_query_var('tpl', null);
    if ( empty($qv)  )
        return $template;
    
    //
    // check $qv and return path to the appropriate file
    //
    $template =  dirname(__FILE__) . '/se385568_minimal_project.php';

    return $template;
}
```

Remember to refresh the rewrite rules (Dashboard -> Settings -> Permalinks -> Save) after adding the code.